# Python extract numbers after a specific string has appeared

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, iteration, data-extraction

I'm new to python and would like to write a script to extract some numbers from a bunch of files. This is a representative example of what I'm trying to do:

```
File_name_1: Bob-01
File content: 
...(Lots of text)
Tea cups: 3
Tea cups: 4
Tea cups: 6
...(Lots of text)
Completed the first task, proceed to the next task.
...(Lots of text)
Tea cups: 7
Termination
```

Let's say we also have another file:

```
File_name_2: Bob-02
File content: 
...(Lots of text)
Tea cups: 2
Tea cups: 7
Tea cups: 3
Tea cups: 8
...(Lots of text)
Completed the first task, proceed to the next task.
...(Lots of text)
Tea cups: 1
Termination.
```

At the moment I have written codes to extract the file name (eg. `Bob-01`), number after each Bob (eg. `01`), and the file content (eg. every line in the first file) and store in a variable called `list_of_file`

```
print list_of_file

[["Bob-01"], 
  01,
 [".......", "Tea Cups: 3", "Tea Cups: 4", "Tea cups: 6", "....", "Completed the first task, proceed to the next task.", "....", "Tea cups: 7", "Termination"],
 ["Bob-02"], 
  02,
 [".......", "Tea Cups: 2", "Tea Cups: 7", "Tea cups: 3", "Tea cups: 8", "....", "Completed the first task, proceed to the next task.", "....", "Tea cups: 1", "Termination]]
```

What I wanted to do is to extract the number of tea cups after the line "Complete first task, proceed to the next task." in each file. So I've written the following code:

```
def get_tea_cups (list_of_files):
   list_of_cup = []
   for line in file[2]:
      if "Completed the first task" in line:
         for line in file[2]:
            if "Tea cups:" in line:
              tea_cups_line = line.split()
              cup_num = tea_cups_line [2]
              list_of_cup.append(file[0], file[1], cup_num)
   return list_of_cup
```

My though process: if I can find "Complete first task" in `list_of_file`, then hopefully I can extract the number of tea cups (eg. 7 for Bob-01 and 1 for Bob-02) after the string containing "Complete first task" has appeared. However, when I executed my code, I seems to have extracted all number of tea cups, which is not what I want.

I think the reason why this has happened is because the if statement will always be true so I ended up extracting all numbers of tea cups.

Is there a way I can get around this problem?? I know if I only do the extraction for one file I can store all the tea cup numbers found as a list and take the last value (by slicing backward). Can I do something similar when I perform extraction for multiple files?

I tried to look around but haven't found anything helpful yet. If you have come across anything which is related to this question please post the link below.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a way. I'd recommend you read the file backwards, find the first occurrence of tea, then break and parse the next file. **My solution assumes your file is fitting into the memory. Most probably this can take a while to read large files**

You can read a file from end by doing:

```
for line in reversed(list(open("filename"))):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Now, to get only the desired tea cups you can do:

```
cups = []
for line in reversed(list(open("filename"))):
    if "Tea cups" in line.rstrip():
        cups.append(line.rstrip().split()[2])
        break
print(cups)
```

Comment: You have to loop through all the files and append to the list all the tea cups you're interested in.

Comment: I was editing my comments and accidentally deleted it.... I was feeding the list_of_file to the for look and clearly that's not working..... I will give it another go and let you know how I get on :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED CODE:
What I would do:

```
.....

for i, line in enumerate(file[2]):
    if "Completed the first task" in line:
         for j in xrange(i+1, len(file[2]):
            if "Tea cups:" in file[2][j]:
              tea_cups_line = file[2][j].split()
              cup_num = tea_cups_line [2]
              list_of_cup.append(file[0], file[1], cup_num)
              break
return list_of_cup
```

It just like your thought but My code count the variant in file[2]. When get 'Completed the first task' start the next one from the text is and go through for loop again until find 'Tea cups'. Take the number and break.

Apologize on my english and hope this help

Comment: I tried the code and got an attribute error: with an arrow pointing at the line `for j in enumerate(i + 1, file[2].length)` 
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'length'` 

I print the variable `i` first 'if' statement got this:
`i         # variable name
4        # line number for the "tea cups" appears after key words in `Bob-01`
5        #line number for the "tea cups" appears after key words in `Bob-02``

Which is as expected. However, now `i` is not iteratable so the remaining code doesn't work...? Also, I tried to print file[2].length and got a type error.

Comment: try: for j in xrange(i+1, len(file[2])